# How can I create a Javascript application to run in the Linux terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, terminal, electron

I want to create a Javascript (using Electron) app, but I want this app to be run and executed with terminal commands, like how you run `git`, is there a way to accomplish this?

I know that python and ruby are better languages for this purpose but I have a reason to use electron.

Comment: Hey, Electron's purpose is to let you create GUI apps using HTML+JS.  If you're just looking to make a command line program, you only NodeJS alone.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-GUI applications, you can just use [node.js](https://nodejs.org) directly. If you want to make a TUI, you can use node.js + a module like [`blessed`](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) (and possibly [`blessed-contrib`](https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib)).

Answer (score 1):

Electron is basically Chromium browser with tabs and all that stuff stripped out, plus a pile of tools to work with the user's desktop environment added in.  It lets you use add HTML and CSS to a Node.JS application to create a GUI.

#### If all you need is a terminal command, Electron is completely unnecessary.

Here's a little pile of links to help you get started creating your command line app:

- [Writing command line applications in Node (Free Code Camp)](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/writing-command-line-applications-in-nodejs-2cf8327eee2)
- [Scripting with Node (Atlassian)](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js with [Commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) npm module would work very well for your requirement.